# How to query across a double M2M in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Consider the following useless example. We have Widgets, Collections of Widgets and Users, each linked by a M2M. One Widget can belong to more than one Collection. Each user can be subscribed to more than one Collection.

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    pass

class WidgetCollection(models.Model):
    widgets = models.ManyToManyField('Widget')

class User(models.Model):
    collections = models.ManyToManyField('WidgetCollection')
```

For any given user I want to list the Widgets. I can loop through the M2Ms but that's really flabby. Can I make Django generate a list of Widgets from in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a *reverse* lookup: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/:

> To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.

Since you want a list of Widgets, start with that model:

```
fredsWidgets = Widget.objects.filter(widgetcollection__user=fred)
```

That should do it.

Comment: Of course, I was thinking about it the wrong way around!